# PPTP VPN missing in "connection type dialogue" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager

There is no PPTP VPN in network manager connection type dialogue.

Packages pptp-linux network-manager-pptp are installed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are missing the GUI components of Network Manager PPTP VPN packages.  `pptp-linux` is the core for PPTP functionality, and `network-manager-pptp` is the core for Network Manager's PPTP functionality, but the core required software and libraries does not equate to the GUI components which show in the Network Manager GUI.

Install the `network-manager-pptp-gnome` package and see if it becomes available under VPN items

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
```